# AngularJS 2 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'company' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I stuck for all day and don't know why. This is the code of component:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {Company} from './company';
import {Job} from './job'
import {CompanyService} from './company-service';

@Component({
  directives: [
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ],
  selector: '[job-list-page]',
  host: {
    class: 'job-list-page app'
  },
  template: require('./job-list-page.html'),
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./job-list-page.scss'), require('./login-page.scss')],
  providers: [CompanyService]
})


export class JobListPage implements OnInit{
  company: Company;
  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getCompany();
  }

  getCompany(){
    this.companyService.getCompany().then(function(company){
      console.log(company);
      this.company = company;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of company-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from './company';
import { Job } from './job'
import { COMPANY } from './mock-company';

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService{
    getCompany(){
        return Promise.resolve(COMPANY);
    }
}
```

I got the object in the getCompany(). But I can't assign the object to the this.company. It will show the error. I don't know why. It looks like I can't assign any value to the variable in the then() method.

the following is the console.log:

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
job-list-page.ts:33 Object {id: "invision", name: "INVISONAPP", logo: "assets/images/pictures/invision-logo-square.png", description: "InVision is the world's leading design collaborati…ernote, Twitter, Adobe, Salesforce and many more.", jobs: Array[1]}
browser_adapter.ts:88 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'company' of null
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'company' of nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup
```

Really need help, Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should use an arrow function to be able to use the lexical this in the callback:

```
getCompany(){
  this.companyService.getCompany().then((company) => {
    console.log(company);
    this.company = company;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But it showed another problem... main.bundle.js:37551ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'logo' of undefined
Why I can't put the property to the html?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't your template but I guess that the Elvis operator could be what you need. For example: `{{company?.logo}}`. Don't forget that you load the company asynchronously (even if the promise is directly resolved) so `company` is undefined at the beginning...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Yes. You are totally right. After I rewrite the code as {{company?.logo}}, it works!! You save my day. Thank you so much :)